# Vim is not reading gzipped files automatically

Tags: unix, vim, vi, putty

I want to see some zipped log files `.gz` in unix through putty. When I open them in `vim`  the contents are not readable. I think vim is not able to unzip them.

Comment: Vim is for text files. It does not unzip files or view compressed files.

Comment: @jahroy: some vim distributions have autocmds for unzipping those files

Comment: vim is a text editor. Not zip viewer.

Comment: Ahmad, can you tell us what vim says when you type `:autocmd`? Is there anything about .gz files? I for example have `:autocmd BufRead *.gz call gzip#read("gzip -dn")`. Do you have gzip executable, and this autocmd?

Comment: @Benoit..@jahroy..my colleagues are able to see it..how ever they too are facing this problem sometime..

Comment: @Benoit..I just need to type ":autocmd?"...right?

Comment: @Ahmad: type `:autocmd BufRead *.gz` and tell me whether you see what I saw (call gzip#read...)

Comment: @Benoit..."ksh: :autocmd:  not found"..I typed ":autocmd BufRead *.log.gz"....* being my file name

Comment: @Ahmad you need to type that **inside vim** after pressing `Esc`. **Not** in ksh console.

Comment: @Benoit...it said "3 files to edit"...but it didn't show the content

Comment: don't type `.log.gz` but `*.gz`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vim is perfectly able to open gzipped files by default, see `:help gzip`.

If it's not possible in your case, you should see:

- if the machine has the `gzip` program,
- if you have the right permissions to use it,
- if your Vim comes with the the gzip standard plugin which should be located at [`/usr/share/vim/vim*/plugin/gzip.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim) and its companion in [`/usr/share/vim/vim*/autoload/gzip.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/autoload/gzip.vim).

Comment: also needs `autoload/gzip.vim`

Comment: You are right. I'll add it to my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Can be a conflict between several plugins, for example file-line https://github.com/bogado/file-line/issues/56

Comment: Also, I just figured out... you can't view gzipped files with 'view', presumably because 'view' puts vim into compatible mode.

Answer (score 2):

Reading compressed files transparently is handled by the gzip vim plugin.  This plugin is only enabled when vim is not in "compatible" mode (see **:help compatible** for more details).  An easy way to ensure "compatible" is not set, is to create an empty .vimrc file in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are really using `vim` and not `vi`. `vi` does not automatically open a gzipped file.

You could add an alias in bash:
`alias vi='vim'`

To make the alias permanent, add it to `~/.bashrc`

Answer (score -1):

Vim is used for text editing. It can not open zip files.

> I want to see some zipped log files .gz in unix through putty.

To see .gz file contents in command line use this command.

```
 zless /path/to/file.gz
```

If zless is not available use `gunzip` and `less` with a pipe

```
gunzip -c /path/to/file.gz | less
```

Comment: -1. vim with some autocmds, in some distributions, automatically gunzips the file at loading time and gzips them back before saving.

Comment: +1. your suggestion are quite a help.. I want to see why its not working on my machine but works for others

Comment: @Ahmad do you have read permission to read that file?

Comment: @Benoit OP said `I want to see some zipped log files .gz in unix through putty`. And this is the answer.  Besides, to only read something using vim is bad idea.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: good remark. removing my -1.